# Comparison of normal Closure with commutator subgroup of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group say generated by $a_{i}$ where $ 1 \leq i \leq n$. Let $G'$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$ and  $H$   be the normal closure of $[a_{i} \ a_{j}]$, $\forall$ $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ where $[a_{i} \ a_{j}]$ is a commutator of $a_{i}$ and $a_{j}$. Then clearly $H$ is contained in $G'$. Does this containment always proper? If not then what extra condition on a group forces this containment to be equality? Like If we put commutativity condition then equality holds.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is contained in $G'$ (obvious).

Since $H$ is normal in $G$, and in $G/H$, the *generators commute*, so $G/H$ is abelian, so by fundamental property of commutator subgroup $G'\subseteq H$.